# Paint a rectangle on the selected cell in Datagrid

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` in my project with the selection mode: `FullRowSelect`. How can I paint a rectangle (like a rectangle on selected cell in `ListView`) on clicked cell? Or change the  color maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've change colour of DataGridViews by handling the CellFormatting event. I do this for either highlighting rows that are in error, or highlighting specific columns;

In my form init method, I have something like;

```
dgvData.CellFormatting += 
            new DataGridViewCellFormattingEventHandler(dgvData_CellFormatting);
```

and the method responsible for the formatting is as follows;

```
        private void dgvData_CellFormatting(object sender,
                                    DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
        {
            bool inError = false;

            // Highlight the row as red if we're in error displaying mode
            if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && fileErrors != null && DisplayErrors)
            {
                // Add +1 to e.rowindex as errors are using a 1-based index
                var dataErrors = (from err in fileErrors
                                  where err.LineNumberInError == (e.RowIndex +1)
                                  select err).FirstOrDefault();
                if (dataErrors != null)
                {
                    e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    inError = true;
                }
            }

            // Set all the rows in a column to a colour, depending on it's mapping.
            Color colourToSet = GetBackgroundColourForColumn(dgvData.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name);
            if (colourToSet != null && !inError)
                e.CellStyle.BackColor = colourToSet;
        }
```

In order to do this for a specific cell, you may also need to handle the MouseUp event on the control and then use the HitTestInfo of the data grid view to work out which cell the hit was actually on.