# how to get 2 lines in datagrid or which control to use in Winforms. so in stead of 1 line use 2 line

Tags: c#, winforms

I like to have 2 lines (rows) in datagrid, which is together. So normally in a grid you have 1 line per row and every next line/row is independent... But I like to have 2 lines. e.g. 1st row the name,address and 2nd line some amounts, or dates.... so every 2 line is together..

what control do I need to use in Winforms to achieve this... I'm newbie, so I prefer simple solution...

e.g. below I like to use   (amount fields should be shown on next line in Datagrid)

```
DocNumber   DocType     DueDate        SupplierNo      SupplierName



Amount     VATAmount   Total Amount


10000       SA          01-05-2012       1025          Supplier-A


12.25       0.25        12.25

10001       SA          12-12-2014       1095          Supplier-B

42.25       5.25        47.00


10002       SB          31-11-2012       1099          Supplier-C

152.25      55.25       192.00
```

Comment: Have you tried breaking your string into multiple lines? (Not sure if it works, though). If all else fail, you'll have to implement your own drawing call.

Comment: not clear what you mean, in designer I do edit columns and can add columns... so how and where to break the string in multi lines? what is drawing call?

Comment: I mean, when you add your data to the `DataGrid`, you could add `"Hello\r\nWorld"` or `"Hello" + Environment.NewLine + "World"`. There is always the possibility, that the control will ignore new lines. That's why, if all else fail, maybe this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13524031/paint-a-rectangle-on-the-selected-cell-in-datagrid

Answer (score 0):

You could add an extra column to your data (i.e DataTable, for instance) where you specify the row order, and then hide it in your control (a DataGridView for instance). 
However this has several drawbacks the first one that comes to mind is that if you click on column headers to sort the grid contents, it will not preserve the order of your rows.
Hope this helps.

Comment: do you mean adding the 2nd row as a row in stead of column???? I see so many controls in the toolbox, is there no any control that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

Well sounds like to me you need to "group" your data if that's what I'm reading right.
However if this is the case I'm afraid Winforms DGVs do not support this as default as far as my understanding is.
I found this link but havent tried it, looks to be a possible work around/hack for it.

[Group Functionality for Winforms Datagridviews](http://blogs.vbcity.com/hotdog/archive/2008/12/19/9226.aspx)

On the plus side there are alot of 3rd party options such as:

[Telerik Controls](http://www.telerik.com/developer-productivity-tools.aspx?gclid=CKfFj-HU0bYCFc3HtAodqVUAvA)

Or my Personnel favorite :

[DevExpress Controls](http://www.devexpress.com/)

Beware though even though u can do trials, You may have to pay for publishing, but worth a look!

Hope this helps!